# How to save php form data for use it later

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple html form along with some php codes in a `index.php` file,
and my question is: how can I save that form data and use them in a diffrent page?
Php code looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //collect form data
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
```

HTML code looks like this:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <p><label>Name</label><br><input type='text' name='name' value=''></p> 
    <p><label>Email</label><br><input type='text' name='email' value=''></p> 
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p> 
</form>
```

Comment: Save where? In file? In database? Else?

Comment: should save in session, for using it on multiple pages

Comment: not wanted to use database, any other idea..??

Comment: save in session ? will it help to get those data's from another page..??

Comment: That's why the concept of [session](http://ie2.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) exists, in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution is save this data in session but this have a limitation to browser close time and it's only assigned to current browser session:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //collect form data
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
}

echo $_SESSION['name'];
echo $_SESSION['email'];

?>
```

For better solution read this solutions and their limitations:

Session - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

File - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Database - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

you can save in session like below code

```html
<?php

session start();
$_SESSION['postdata'] = $_POST;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if this is what you want, since you dont specify, but you could save it via cookies with javascript, and then capture it with php.

JAVASCRIPT

```
       //Call this in the html
         function Example(element){

        var name = $(elemt).find('name').text();
        document.cookie = escape('variable') + '=' + escape(name) + '' +  '; path=/';
```

PHP

```
      $name= $_COOKIE['variable']))
```